# Groupby given percentiles of the values of the chosen DataFrame column

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

Imagine that I have a `DataFrame` with columns that contain only real values.

```
>> df        
          col1   col2      col3  
0     0.907609     82  4.207991 
1     3.743659   1523  6.488842 
2     2.358696    324  5.092592  
3     0.006793      0  0.000000  
4    19.319746  11969  7.405685
```

I want to group it by quartiles (or any other percentiles specified by me) of the chosen column (e.g., `col1`), to perform some operations on these groups. Ideally, I would like to do something like:

```
df.groupy( quartiles_of_col1 ).mean()  # not working, how to code quartiles_of_col1?
```

The output should give the mean of each of the columns for four groups corresponding to the quartiles of `col1`. Is this possible with the `groupby` command? What's the simplest way of achieving it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't have a computer to test it right now, but I think you can do it by: `df.groupby(pd.cut(df.col0, np.percentile(df.col0, [0, 25, 75, 90, 100]), include_lowest=True)).mean()`. Will update after 150mins.

Some explanations:

```
In [42]:
#use np.percentile to get the bin edges of any percentile you want 
np.percentile(df.col0, [0, 25, 75, 90, 100])
Out[42]:
[0.0067930000000000004,
 0.907609,
 3.7436589999999996,
 13.089311200000001,
 19.319745999999999]
In [43]:
#Need to use include_lowest=True
print df.groupby(pd.cut(df.col0, np.percentile(df.col0, [0, 25, 75, 90, 100]), include_lowest=True)).mean()
                       col0     col1      col2
col0                                          
[0.00679, 0.908]   0.457201     41.0  2.103996
(0.908, 3.744]     3.051177    923.5  5.790717
(3.744, 13.0893]        NaN      NaN       NaN
(13.0893, 19.32]  19.319746  11969.0  7.405685
In [44]:
#Or the smallest values will be skiped
print df.groupby(pd.cut(df.col0, np.percentile(df.col0, [0, 25, 75, 90, 100]))).mean()
                       col0     col1      col2
col0                                          
(0.00679, 0.908]   0.907609     82.0  4.207991
(0.908, 3.744]     3.051177    923.5  5.790717
(3.744, 13.0893]        NaN      NaN       NaN
(13.0893, 19.32]  19.319746  11969.0  7.405685
```

Comment: This works for me! Brilliant use of cut! Thanks champ

Comment: Example added. Turns out you also want to set `include_lowest` to be `True`, otherwise the smallest numbers will be skipped. Edited. Cheers!

Comment: I get back an array of nans :/

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will solve your problem. It is not pretty but I hope it will work for you

```
    import pandas as pd
    import random 
    import numpy as np
    ## create a mock df as example. with column A, B, C and D
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))

    ## select dataframe based on the quantile of column A, using the quantile method.
    df[df['A'] < df['A'].quantile(0.3)].mean()
```

this will print

```
A   -1.157615
B    0.205529
C   -0.108263
D    0.346752
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Well, this is ok for one percentile, but I'm specifically searching for a solution that will get the ``mean`` for each of the groups defined by the percentiles/`q`-quantiles.

Comment: how about doing a for loop that replaces the quantile value ?

Comment: Yes, this is a possibility, but it's not elegant nor efficient. Imagine that you have a big DF and you want to split it into 10-cuantiles. Doing a loop would mean that you go 10 times over the DF just to group your data.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas has a native solution, `pandas.qcut`, to this as well:

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.qcut.html